# Firebase -- Document references must have an even number of segments, but Rezepte has 1

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Ok so I generated a random name of a document and now I'm trying to get data from that document.

```
        namereference
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                            String names = documentSnapshot.get("dokumentnamen").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                            String [] namelist = names.split(", ");
                            Random random = new Random();
                            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(namelist.length);
                            randomrezeptname = namelist[randomNumber];

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Generating a random name works fine and the name exists.
But now I'm trying to use that String in a DocumentReference within another void but it doesn't work at all.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("Rezepte").document(this.randomrezeptname);
```

I always get the same error:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Rezepte has 1

I tried using the content of the String and put it directly in the DocumentReference and it worked. But I have to use a variable since It's supposed to show a random document.
Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Do your random string has any special characters in it?

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e No, it doesn't. Just plain text

Comment: Basically, the error is because in Firestore data is hierarchical. You can only have a document within a collection (not any collection) and can only have collection within a document (not any other document). So going in this order, your documents should always be at even numbers in hierarchy.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e  Yeah but I only have a collection that contains a document with data. That's all. So I don't know where there might be any hierarchical problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say

> I tried using the content of the String and put it directly in the DocumentReference and it worked

You mean that you ran

```
DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("Rezepte").document("a_random_recipe_name");
```

And it worked, suggesting that your hierarchy is fine.

Are you sure that the random name generator thing actually sets `randomrezeptname` before you try to use it to access a random document? I mean to say that if you run:

```
1) namereference.get().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener);
2) System.out.println(this.randomrezeptname)
3) DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("Rezepte").document(this.randomrezeptname)
```

Lines 2 and 3 will probably run before OnSuccessListener is run, meaning you'll have some odd behavior around whatever `randomrezeptname` is before OnSuccessListener sets it. OnSuccessListener runs some time later, on the main thread, but after an asynchronous method returns.

Comment: I had a function getting a random name and another function using that name. I called them both in the onCreate method. Now I'm only calling the function getting a random name. I'm calling the other function within the onSuccessListener of the function called in the onCreate method. Thanks!